# Subdomains with multiple dots best practices

Tags: dns, subdomain

Anyone know of the pros and cons of having multiple dots in a subdomain in relation to web application development?

I was wondering which one of the naming schema would work best:

**qa.myproject.example.com** (this one has one extra dot)

or

**qa-myproject.example.com**

Comment: Really depends on what you're doing and how consistent you're going to be. Remember that adding "extra dots" is creating additional subdomains (ie, in `qa.myproject.mydomain.com`, `qa` is a subdomain of `myproject.mydomain.com`).

Comment: what harm does it cause to create more subdomains under a main domain? from a DNS configuration we just setup a new CNAME right or is there more to it when it is a sub-domain of a sub-domain

Comment: There's really no harm, it's just something to be aware of (for things like SSL certs or apps that have logic to traverse subdomains). From a technical perspective, `qa.myproject` is not the same as `qa-myproject`, but from a functional perspective, they *can* be similar, if you're simply looking to segregate things off of your main domain.

Comment: Late follow-up, but: any further info on SSL certs? Like, would a sub-sub-domain (`qa.myproject.mydomain.con`) not need to re-establish an SSL connection, or log in, etc. if one was made on the subdomain (`myproject.mydomain.com`) while using a different subdomain (`qa-myproject.mydomain.com`) *would* require re-logging in, etc since it's distinct from `myproject.mydomain.com`? Any other considerations along those lines?

Answer (score 3):

i guess there is no harm. provided your domain registrar is flexible for multi-level domain. a.example.com and a.b.example.com is just a record under example.com. you can also switch to DNS provider of you own choice by updating nameservers in you domain register portal.

i found quite useful info here - https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/56984/subdomain-with-dot/56985#56985